# Custom styled ordered list centering the digit

Tags: css

I'm making a custom styled ordered list.

I'm styling the list element so it contains a circle (border-radius:50%;) with the number centered inside of it. I'm having trouble with positioning the numbers perfectly centered to the circle(green) background. If I add padding to the inside element then the double digit numbers are off centered. Is there a solution or a better way to do this and that's also responsive?

Here is the code link https://jsfiddle.net/awexkma6/1/

(HTML)

```
<ol class="custom-counter">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ol>
```

CSS

```
.custom-counter {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.custom-counter li {
    counter-increment: step-counter;
    position: relative;
    padding: .5em 0 .5em 3em;
    color: #6d6e73;
    border-bottom: .175em solid #e5e5e5;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
.custom-counter li:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    content: counter(step-counter);
    background-color:green;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32446081/670377) yesterday, but here we go again:

The trick is to add a fixed width and height with `text-align: center`, and `line-height` equal to height:

```
.custom-counter li {
    counter-increment: step-counter;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    color: #6d6e73;
    border-bottom: .175em solid #e5e5e5;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    //Add this
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/awexkma6/2/

Comment: Sorry I did search for this question I couldn't find a good way to do this. But Yes that works --  thank you so much for explaining it.

Answer (score 1):

Add some padding to your css like this:

```
enter code here.custom-counter li:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    content: counter(step-counter);
    background-color:green;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    padding: 7px 0 0 7px;
}
```

Comment: There is no HTML in your snippet ;)

Answer (score 0):

Update your css style with this:

```
.custom-counter li:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    content: counter(step-counter);
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharkhatiwada/awexkma6/3/